# Call a JavaScript function in a different library

Tags: javascript, xpages

It seems to me that this should be possible. In an XPages application I have two ServerSide JavaScript Libraries **jsMain** and **jsSave**. In the jsMain I have this Script:

```
function thisAction(msg:String){
    try{

    switch(msg){
    case "Save" :
        print("This action = " + msg);
        if (jsSave.processAction()){
            print("jsSave.processAction returned true");
            return true;
            break;
        }else{
            print("jsSave.processAction returned false");
            return false;
            break;
        }
    default:
        print("In default msg is " + msg);
        return false;
        break;
    }
    }catch(e){
        print("thisAction Failed in jsMain " + e.toString())
    }
}
```

In a button on an XPage I call `thisAction("Save")` and it invokes the thisAction function, now when the msg is Save I want to call the function `processAction` but it resides in the JS Library jsSave. What I have above fails with the error:
 ***thisAction Failed in jsMain 'jsSave' not found***

So is there a way to tell this code that processAction is in an different SSJS Library?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add

```
import jsSave
```

on top of your jsMain library, no quotes, no filename extension: you will be able to use functions declared inside jsSave from jsMain.

Answer (score 0):

If jsMain was loaded first, you can't call a function in jsSave. However, you can call a function in jsMain from jsSave because it was loaded first.

Answer (score 0):

Your page should include both the js libraries and jsSave library should be first.

```
<script src="jsSave.js"></script>
<script src="jsMain.js"></script>
```

Also please refer to modular javascript pattern.

Comment: my issue is that I can't add the jsSave resource to the calling page, because I need to isolate the calls in jsMain. In other words for design reasons I only want to have the resource jsMain defined on my my main page, then jsMain will call different functions from different libraries based on the value of msg. I am allowing changes to jsSave but not to the main poage if additional functions need to be added.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried adding both libraries to your page?  I'd think that would work.  Alternatively I THINK at the top of the library you can do something similar to the LotusScript :

```
use "myLibrary"
```

I want to say you do :

```
import("jsSave");
```

But I'm not positive of the syntax.  I'm sure I've done it once long ago though.

Comment: According to the JS documentation that I could find it would appear that something like this should work
import { processAction } from "jsSave.js";
but the compiler does not like the import call, tried several different variants.

Comment: David -- I know I can add both libraries to my main page and get it to work, but I'm trying to isolate changes to the jsMain instead of the main page. The main page is refreshed from a template, but jsMain is not so I want the local developer to be able to make changes to jsMain (add additional functions) without them being overwritten on a refresh.

Comment: Bill, I THINK you do import("libraryName") or something like that at the TOP of the SSJS library.  you don't import the method itself I don't believe.

Comment: Tried it several different ways according to the documentation I found it should work either way. According to this:
import defaultMember from "module-name";
import * as name from "module-name";
import { member } from "module-name";
import { member as alias } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 } from "module-name";
import { member1 , member2 as alias2 , [...] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, { member [ , [...] ] } from "module-name";
import defaultMember, * as name from "module-name";
import "module-name";

wonder if it is an issue with the JS compiler in XPages?